# Multiple activities calling same activity for result

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Suppose I have 3 activities.

- First
- Second
- Result.

First and Second both call Result activity by `startActivityForResult()`. 
In Result, on basis of calling activity, I want to return different results.

Is there any way to decide which one has called Result Activity and return result to that activity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the calling activity using `getCallingActivity ()`

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple activities on top at the same time. Are you trying to have them run in order, one after the other?

One way to accomplish this is to start each activity for result:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Where you use the request code to track when activity is running. Then, in onActivityResult you can start the next one:

```
protected void  onActivityResult  (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent  data) {
  if (requestCode < NUM_ACTIVITIES) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode + 1);
  }
}
```

If you want to have some of the activities immediatly in the background, you can chain them together by calling startActivity in each Activity's onCreate. If you start a new Activity in onCreate before creating any views, the activity will never be visible.

```
protected void  onCreate  (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  int numLeft = getIntent().getIntExtra("numLeft");
  if (numLeft > 0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("numLeft", numLeft - 1);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you calling activity finish the activity with setresult

```
Intent in = new Intent();
setResult(100, in);
finish();
```

In your first activity

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(Tag, "Result: " + Integer.toString(resultCode));

    if (resultCode == 200) {
            Log.i(Tag, "second");           
    } else if (resultCode == 100) {
            Log.i(Tag, "activity");
    } 
}
```